Jacoco code coverage report with karate testcases and maven project , original code and karate testcases present in different project
I want to create jacoco code coverage report of my maven project. My Main code present in different maven project and testcases are present in different maven project. I want code coverage report of my main code based on my testcases.
Kindly help me on this with step by step in details. Thanking you in advance.
Want to create jacoco test coverage report of my maven project based on my karate testcases present in different maven project.

hope someone else can help, you can try searching other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+jacoco

First can you show some examples of the code as well as the pom files.. furthermore why are the test cases in a different project than the code?
